# Does MySQL delete references?

Tags: mysql, sql-delete

I have a 'look-up' table with pre-set values (was informed it's better than ENUM)

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_payment_type (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    description VARCHAR(25)
);
INSERT INTO tbl_payment_type
    (description)
VALUES
    ('PAYPAL'),
    ('DEBIT CARD'),
    ('CREDIT CARD'),
    ('CASH ON DELIVERY');
```

Now, each of my Orders contains a payment type.

```
CREATE TABLE tbl_order (
    id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    ...
    payment_type INT,
    FOREIGN KEY(payment_type) REFERENCES tbl_payment_type(id)
) AUTO_INCREMENT = 1000;
```

I am currently using MyISAM but might try out InnoDB in the future (I'm unsure if that affects the question).

And finally, the question is, if I try to delete a record from `tbl_payment_type`, will that cause MySQL to automatically delete all records from `tbl_order` that contained this payment type?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MyISAM doesn't support foreign keys so nothing happens while using this storage provider.

InnoDB supports foreign keys, and by default it will restrict DELETE and UPDATES in no foreign matches. This behavior can be changed with by adding ON DELETE and ON UPDATE options. See [FOREIGN KEY Constraints](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) on the MySQL website.

Comment: Alright thanks. I guess I'll stick with MyISAM for simplicity then.

Comment: What's the point of the question about foreign keys if you use an engine that ignores them? :)

Comment: @N.B. Hmmmm, when I designed the DB on paper, naturally I made a relational database. When I converted that to MySQL, I didn't realise FK wasn't supported by default. I have more to learn before I start using InnoDB. At least with these left in it will be quick to change over if I need to in future. Plus when looking at the SQL source code it helps you to understand what's going on with the FK constraints left in.

Comment: I've to correct you on one thing - FKs are supported by default because latest version of MySQL has InnoDB as default engine. I understand that you designed the db on the paper, however MySQL is a bit special compared to other dbs out there, and it's due to pluggable storage engine architecture which means each of them brings something different to the table. You don't have to enforce integrity via foreign keys, some people opt not to do it in order to gain performance.

Answer (score 1):

It will give you an error if you try to `DELETE` an entry of `payment_type` from `tbl_payment_type`

```
delete from `test`.`tbl_payment_type` where `id`='2'
```

> Error:1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key
>   constraint fails (`test`.`tbl_order`, CONSTRAINT `tbl_order_ibfk_1`
>   FOREIGN KEY (`payment_type`) REFERENCES `tbl_payment_type` (`id`))

Comment: @MalheshPatil This only applies to InnoDB, right? And could you show us how to delete a record with a FK properly if you use InnoDB?

Comment: BTW: This applied to only InnoDB type incase of MyISAM there is no relationship hence there is no effect on deletion on another table

Comment: First you have to delete all entries w.r.t `payment_type` from `tbl_order` then only you can delete an entry from `tbl_payment_type`

For example : if you want to delete an entry for `Paypal`from `tbl_payment_type` you should delete all entries from `tbl_order` which has `id`=1 then only you can delete an entry from `tbl_payment_type` which has `id`=1 (Paypal)

Comment: Oh right so I would have to rewrite the `payment_type` to null in `tbl_order` to preserve the order records. Thanks.